# Not able to load default template file for the application

Tags: layout, magento-1.8

I have included the following code in {mytheme}/layout/page.xml. But, my application is not loading the default template file. Is there any thing wrong in my code.

Please help me.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- Default layout, loads most of the pages -->
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head"></block>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/onecolumn.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```